# How to set up borders and style while image swapping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a simple code, when i mouseover on image it is being changed, and when i mouseleave it returns first src value:

```
<img id="myImage" onmouseover="changeImage()" onmouseleave="resetImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";   

}

function resetImage() {
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
         image.src =  "pic_bulboff.gif";
}
</script>
```

now i want to set up border, also when i mouseover on the image, it should be have border, for example: border: 2px solid red;
how co i do this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
css:

```
.boder{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

js:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg";
    image.setAttribute('class','boder');

}

function resetImage() {
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
     image.src =  "pic_bulboff.gif";
     image.removeAttribute('class','boder');
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/bosoxebihu/edit?html,css,js,output)